# Unable to Send Data From View To controller Action .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

Just sending a int Data from View To Controller Action. but the controller action is not receiving that int data/ cannot map that int data.

my controller =>

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ConfirmNewBatchRequest(int? id)
    {
        if ((id?? 0) == 0)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Studentassignbatche ConfirmStudentassignbatche = db.Studentassignbatches.Find(id);
        Batche FindBatche = db.Batches.Find(ConfirmStudentassignbatche.batch_code);

        if (ConfirmStudentassignbatche == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ConfirmStudentassignbatche.StatusCode = 1;
        db.Financeofstudents.Add(new Financeofstudent()
        {
            UserId = ConfirmStudentassignbatche.UserId,
            batch_code = ConfirmStudentassignbatche.batch_code,
            debit = FindBatche.amount,
            credit = 0,
            balance = FindBatche.amount,
            lastTrunsaction = DateTime.Now,
            entry_date = DateTime.Now
        });
        TryUpdateModel(ConfirmStudentassignbatche, new string[] { "StatusCode" });
        db.SaveChanges();

        TempData["BatchConfirmSuccess"] = "Success";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

and my view =>

```
    @using Something
    @model IEnumerable<Studentassignbatche>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Confirm New Batch Request From Student";
        IEnumerable<Course> CoursesTable = TempData["Courses"] as IEnumerable<Course>;
        IEnumerable<UserDetail> UserDetailTable = TempData["UserDetails"] as IEnumerable<UserDetail>;
    }

    @section PageDescription{
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>
                @ViewBag.Title
                <small>Tsms-admin</small>
            </h1>
        </section>
    }

    &nbsp;

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-inverse table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.Label("Student Name")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.batch_code)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.Label("Vendor Name")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.adding_date)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            @{
                int counter = 1;
            }
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @counter
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @{
                            var UserDetailsId = UserDetailTable.Where(x => x.UserId == item.UserId).Select(x => x.id).FirstOrDefault();
                            var name = UserDetailTable.Where(x => x.UserId == item.UserId).Select(x => x.fullname).FirstOrDefault();
                        }
                        @Html.ActionLink(name, "Details", "Students", new { id = UserDetailsId }, null)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink(item.batch_code, "Details", "Batche", new { id = item.batch_code }, null)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink(item.name, "Details", "Course", new { id = item.name }, null)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @{
                            var vendorname = CoursesTable.Where(x => x.name == item.name).Select(x => x.vendor_heading).FirstOrDefault();
                        }
                        <label style="font-weight:normal !important">@vendorname</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.adding_date)
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:100px;">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm())
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelitem => item.id)

                            <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-success" /> 
                            </div>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
                counter++;
            }
        </table>
    </div>
```

The rendered form inside the loop looks like this:

```
<form action="/Admin/ConfirmNewBatchRequest" method="post"> 
  <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="K4GmhPUCkcqqclPtxW7F1YpiT_6mQBBZu7Wi8JtfQDMWdmCPMQsbj‌​Bfmtr9t8pSBrOV6Yixhh‌​tz0B-OfMtxj4Y8dOwrdR‌​BXlz9v0sD7O8YE1" />
  <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field id must be a number." data-val-required="The id field is required." id="item_id" name="item.id" type="hidden" value="3" /> 
  <div class="form-actions no-color"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-success" /> 
  </div> 
</form>
```

and here is how my model binds with the view =>

```
public class Studentassignbatche
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "User Id Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(12, ErrorMessage = "The Max length Of User ID is 12 Character!")]
    [RegularExpression("[1-3]{2}-[0-9]{5}-[123]{1}|[1-3]{2}-[0-9]{7}-[123]{1}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Id,It should [xx]-[xxxxx]-[x] or [xx]-[xxxxxxx]-[x]!")]
    [Display(Name = "User ID")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// /////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Course Name Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(700, ErrorMessage = "The Max Length For Course Name Is 700 Character!")]
    [Display(Name = "Course Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// /////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Batch Code Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(700, ErrorMessage = "The Max Length For Batch Code Is 700 Character!")]
    [Display(Name = "Batch Code")]
    public string batch_code { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ///////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Status Is Required!")]
    [RegularExpression("^(?:complete|Complete|in progress|In progress)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Status!")]
    [Display(Name = "Current Status")]
    public string status { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ////////
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Course Completion Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime,ErrorMessage="Invalid Date!")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> completion_date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Date Of Addition")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime,ErrorMessage="Invalid Date!")]
    public DateTime adding_date { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// /////////
    /// </summary>
    [RegularExpression("^[01]{1}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Status Code!")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Status Code Is Required!")]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    //relationship with anothere  table------

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// //////
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("name")]
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ///////
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("batch_code")]
    public Batche Batche { get; set; }
}
```

and on controller when I debug I found out that =>
[image]
and i try using =>

```
    public ActionResult ConfirmNewBatchRequest(Studentassignbatche Studentassignbatche)
    {
        if (Studentassignbatche == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

but on debut it is still showing me a null object .

why this is happening because in view side it can generate more than one `<form></form>`. but as far as I can understand if the view generate more than one `<form></form>` still every form will get one hidden input field.
and when the form will submit it will that particular hidden field which is associated with that `<form>`. Or One thing my URL look like `http://localhost:43847/Admin/ConfirmNewBatchRequest` is there any problem with URL ? Then why this problem is arising, and How to get rid of that problem.

Comment: what does the rendered HTML look like? Does the Hidden field you created definitely contain the right ID?

Comment: @ADyson html look like==>   `<form action="/Admin/ConfirmNewBatchRequest"  method="post">
 <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="K4GmhPUCkcqqclPtxW7F1YpiT_6mQBBZu7Wi8JtfQDMWdmCPMQsbjBfmtr9t8pSBrOV6Yixhhtz0B-OfMtxj4Y8dOwrdRBXlz9v0sD7O8YE1" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field id must be a number." data-val-required="The id field is required." id="item_id" name="item.id" type="hidden" value="3" />                       
 <div class="form-actions no-color">
     <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-success" /> 
    </div>
</form> `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your form and your postback method don't match.

In your form, the rendered hidden field's `name` is `item.id`. However, your action method expects simply a single int called `id`. The form will submit it as if `id` is part of an object called `item`.

The HTML helper you've used to render the field is designed for when you want to post back the whole model, not just one field - i.e. in that case your action method would have to accept an object of type `Studentassignbatche`.

To fix this, you can use the simpler version of the HiddenField helper:

```
@Html.Hidden("id", item.id)
```

This should render something like:

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="3" />
```

which will mean that the `name` matches the name expected by your action method.